# How to convert enums to Map<int, String> in dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following `enum` definition:

```
enum ContentType {
  calendar,
  order,
  car,
  operator
}
```

in my code i want to call a function like this:

```
...

                DropDownSettingsTile(
                    title: "Column",
                    settingKey: SettingKeys.userColumnSelection,
                    selected: 0,
                    values: ContentType.values.asMap(),   // <---- Fails !!
                  onChange: (value){
                      print("setting change to: $value");
                  },
                ),
...
```

as mentioned above, I get a problem here, with following error:
`The argument type 'Map<int, ContentType>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<int, String>'.`

I thought, in my simple mind, that `values` from `enum` sets was represented as `Strings`, but no...

...what is the best way to convert an `enum` mapped set from my `<int, ContentType>` to `<int, String>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this for example

```
ContentType.values.map((e) => e.toString()).toList().asMap()
```

Though I doubt that is exactly what you want because the Strings will be in the form of "ContentType.calendar" for example. So maybe this is what you want:

```
ContentType.values.map((e) => e.toString().split(".")[1]).toList().asMap()
```

EDIT:
as jamesdlin pointed out, you can also just write

```
ContentType.values.map((e) => e.name).toList().asMap()
```

Comment: As of Dart 2.14 (I think), you can use [`e.name`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/EnumName/name.html) instead of needing to manually split the `toString()` representation.

Comment: @jamesdlin you are right. I actually wasn't aware of that. thanks